# Typoscript: how to select a set of subpages or how to make a condition based on page id

Tags: select, typo3, conditional-statements, typoscript

Currently I'm working with `PIDinRootline`. This works fine.

```
[PIDinRootline=8,9]
    //do something
[end]

[PIDinRootline=6,7,11]
    //do something
[end]
```

Now I want to address a set of subpages under 7. Currently an all pages where the parent has the id 7 has the same code. But now I want something different on page id 128 and all its subpages. Is it allowed to make something like

```
[PIDinRootline=8,9]
    //do something
[end]

[PIDinRootline=6,7,11]
    //do something different
[end]
[PIDinRootline=128]
    //do something
[end]
```

So the page 128 is under 7. The setting is overwritten because first the settings from PIDinRootline=7 takes place and then the settings from PIDinRootline=128. Is this allowed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Definetely allowed. Just make sure you define conditions in the same order as quoted.
You can actually leave out some of the `[end]` conditions.
Note: This works for TYPO3 up to version 8 / 9.3:

```
[PIDinRootline=8,9]
    //do something
[PIDinRootline=6,7,11]
    //do something different
[PIDinRootline=128]
    //do something
[end]
```

The old condition syntax was deprecated with TYPO3 9.4. The new syntax is based on the [symfony expression language](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language.html) and looks like this:

```
[8 in tree.rootLineIds || 9 in tree.rootLineIds]
    //do something
[6 in tree.rootLineIds || 7 in tree.rootLineIds || 11 in tree.rootLineIds]
    //do something different
[128 in tree.rootLineIds]
    //do something
[end]
```

Other useful page related conditions are (old syntax):

- `[globalVar = TSFE:id = 128]` // Only on PID 128
- `[PIDupinRootline = 128]` // Only on subpages of PID 128 (PID 128 not included)
- `[treeLevel = 1]` // All pages that belong to tree level 1 (subpages of
  root level)

Check the [TYPO3 reference](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Conditions/Index.html) for the new condition syntax.